# Разделение строк df pandas на определенный делитель

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Подскажите как можно разделить строки на кратное количество.
Из такого

```
   A    B   C
0   a   b   16  # Делитель 2
1   a   c   22  # Делитель 3
2   b   d   12  # Делитель 5
```

Получить такой

```
    A   B   C
0   a   b   2
0   a   b   2
0   a   b   2
0   a   b   2
0   a   b   2
0   a   b   2
0   a   b   2
0   a   b   2
1   a   c   3
1   a   c   3
1   a   c   3
1   a   c   3
1   a   c   3
1   a   c   3
1   a   c   3
1   a   c   1
2   b   d   5
2   b   d   5
2   b   d   1
2   b   d   1
```

Есть такое решение, где один общий делитель, не знаю как сделать по условию

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['a', 'a', 'b'], B=['b', 'c', 'd'], C=[16, 22, 12]))

m = np.array([4, 1])
dm = list(zip(*np.divmod(df.C.values, m[0])))

rep = [sum(x) for x in dm]
new = np.concatenate([m.repeat(x) for x in dm])

df.loc[df.index.repeat(rep)].assign(C=new)
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы по столбцу В использовать разные делители, значения в словаре

```
d = {'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `apply` и lambda функцией, в которую передается Series (очередная строка фрейма) и словарь. Размножение строк реализовано с помощью `explode()`. Плюс вспомогательные преобразования.

```
d = {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 5}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['a', 'a', 'b'], B=['b', 'c', 'd'], C=[16, 22, 12]))
df.C = df.apply(lambda x: [d[x.B]] * (x.C // d[x.B]) + [1] * (x.C % d[x.B]), axis=1)
df = df.explode('C')
print(df)
```

```
   A  B  C
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  1
2  b  d  5
2  b  d  5
2  b  d  1
2  b  d  1
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
df["C"] = df.apply(lambda x:  np.divmod(x["C"], d.get(x["B"])), axis=1)
df["C"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.concatenate((np.full(x["C"][0], d.get(x["B"])),
                                                 (np.full(x["C"][1], 1)))), axis=1)
df = df.explode("C")
```

df:

```
   A  B  C
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  2
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  3
1  a  c  1
2  b  d  5
2  b  d  5
2  b  d  1
2  b  d  1
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо